# Git pull from server dont detect merge

Tags: git, gitlab

I try to work with git in my project. I created a new project in gitlab and I make two branches ( `master`, `developement`), and after push and merge and accepting merge.

I try to use this deploy  script to pull in my server:    https://gist.github.com/madalinignisca/9323683 but the pull doesn't work, the git status in the server is always

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Any help please?

Comment: _"after push and merge and accepting merge"_ you mean you sent a _pull request_ which was accepted and merged? Does `git log` show something you do not expect? Does `git remote -v` show your `origin` points at your fork or the main repo?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the correct repository? Are you sure that `origin/master` is updated after you merge? Can you pull down new changes locally but it doesn't work on your server?

Comment: yes i mean after request is accepted, when i connect with shh and make `git pull` it work good, but when i execute the file [link](https://gist.github.com/madalinignisca/9323683) 
deploy.php it dont work

Comment: This is the file in my server to automatically deploy in the server  [deploy.php](http://work.benelouafi.tn/pizzaStand/deploy.php)